# Efficient merge overlapping intervals in same pandas dataframe with start and finish columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm merging overlapping intervals in pandas dataframe, and looking for efficient way to do it in pandas, besides the regular algorithms of running on rows 1 by 1. how can I do it in pandas?

I have tried regular overlapping algo of running on each row and ask if current row.start < last_end. and this worked for me.

Say I have input of the following dataframe

```
df:
    START   FINISH
0   0.000000    10.000000
1   10.000000   8700.182997
2   0.000000    10.000000
3   10.000000   9720.687227
4   9850.123    9990.000000
```

I would expect the output to be as following:

```
df:
    START   FINISH
0   0.000000    9720.687227
2   9850.123    9990.000000
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do it using only pandas

```py
import pandas as pd
import io

## load data

raw ="""START,FINISH
0.000000    ,10.000000
10.000000   ,4500.182997
5000.00    ,7000.000000
6000   ,8500.687227
9850.123,9990.000000
"""

buf_bytes = io.StringIO(raw)
df=pd.read_csv(buf_bytes)

## solution

df.sort_values("START", inplace=True)

## This line compares if START of next row is greater than FINISH of current
## row ("shift" shifts down FINISH by one row). The value of expression before
## cumsum will be True if interval breaks (i.e. cannot be merged), so  
## cumsum will increment group value when interval breaks (cum sum treats True=1, False=0)
df["group"]=(df["START"]>df["FINISH"].shift()).cumsum()

## this returns min value of "START" column from a group and max value fro m "FINISH"
result=df.groupby("group").agg({"START":"min", "FINISH": "max"})
display(result)
```

**output**

```
 START       FINISH
group                       
0         0.000  4500.182997
1      5000.000  8500.687227
2      9850.123  9990.000000
```

Comment: can you please add some explanation on the solution ? for example, pandas function you used and their affect on results?

Comment: you are welcome, I have added few comments on solution above hope that helps

Comment: it does! all clear, thanks, one last question, how can I get rid of "group" in results ?

Comment: set index name blank
result.index.name = ""

Comment: sorry I meant the whole column under group

Comment: that is index of dataframe, I don't think we can remove it. You can  use other values or column as index using "reindex" function

Comment: Got it, thanks alot, everything worked perfectly for me

Comment: @DevKhadka This doesn't work for multiple overlapping ranges. For instance: [[0,10], [10,4500], [20, 30], [40, 50], [60, 70], [5000, 7000], [6000-8500]]

Answer (score 10):

The above answer is inspiring but there is something need to be improved.

(1) It should be documented that `shift()` will shift up one record, not down.
(2) It does not consider when a row is within the boundary of the previous record. Just add `cummax()` and will solve.

Here is the modified code:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

## load data

raw ="""START,FINISH
0.000000    ,10.000000
2.000000    ,3.000000
10.000000   ,4500.182997
5000.00    ,7000.000000
6000   ,8500.687227
9850.123,9990.000000
"""

buf_bytes = io.StringIO(raw)
df=pd.read_csv(buf_bytes)

## solution

df.sort_values("START", inplace=True)

## This line compares if START of present row is greater than largest FINISH in previous 
## rows ("shift" shifts up FINISH by one row). The value of expression before
## cumsum will be True if interval breaks (i.e. cannot be merged), so
## cumsum will increment group value when interval breaks (cum sum treats True=1, False=0)


df["group"]=(df["START"]>df["FINISH"].shift().cummax()).cumsum()

print(df)

## this returns min value of "START" column from a group and max value fro m "FINISH"
result=df.groupby("group").agg({"START":"min", "FINISH": "max"})
print(result)
```

output:

```
          START       FINISH
group                       
0         0.000  4500.182997
1      5000.000  8500.687227
2      9850.123  9990.000000
```

Results from the unmodified solution:

```
          START       FINISH
group                       
0         0.000    10.000000
1        10.000  4500.182997
2      5000.000  8500.687227
3      9850.123  9990.000000
```